# Two select statements in SUBSTR within a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I run the following sql query alone, I am getting the correct result of a three letter value

```
(select substr((select code from (select  qq.id, qq.code from contacts qq where qq.code like 'FB%' and qq.ref_no = 3359245 order by id desc ) where rownum=1),3,6) from dual)
```

But when I run the same query in the following way,

```
select ce.ref_no, 
(select substr((select code from (select  qq.id, qq.code from contacts qq where qq.code like 'FB%' and qq.ref_no = ce.ref_no order by id desc ) where rownum=1),3,6) from dual) "FEEDBACK"
from contacts ce
where ce.ref_no = 3359245;
```

I am getting the following error

```
ORA-00904: "CE"."REF_NO": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 62 Column: 137
```

my data set is as follows :

```
14494895    FBBOM
14494896    FBDEL
14494897    FBBOM
14494898    FBDEL
14494902    FBDEL
14494903    FBDEL
```

I want to get FBDEL from 14494903

Comment: Trying to join within the inner select will not work. You could have the Select as a table and join to contacts ce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using correlated subqueries, Oracle has a limit on how "deep" it recognizes the outer query.  It can only go down one level.

You have the correlation condition two levels down, so the compiler does not recognize the outer alias.

I think you can do what you want more easily with analytic functions.  I think this is what you want:

```
select  ce.ref_no,
        substr(max(code) keep (dense_rank first order by (case when code like 'FB%' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
                                                          id desc
                              ), 3, 6)
from contacts ce
where ce.ref_no = 3359245
group by ce.ref_no;
```

This does assume that there is an `FB` record, so it might return the wrong thing in other cases.  (You could check for that with additional logic.)

Comment: when I try to run the query, it is saying `ORA-30492: One of FIRST or LAST keywords is expected.
30492. 00000 -  "One of FIRST or LAST keywords is expected."
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 46`

Comment: @Mrk . . . I fixed the syntax.

Comment: now I am getting `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 8` I have edited my question and added my dataset to the question

Comment: thank you for your insight. I used analytical functions to achieve my goal. Anyway if this query would have worked, I wouldn't have gone for many joins.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Contacts table and hence the alias ce is not visible to the inner query